# Трансляция ST в C++

Tags: c#, c++, трансляция

Передо мной стоит задача – написать на языке С# программу, которая будет преобразовывать исходный код, написанный на языке **ST**, в исходный код, на **С++**. *ST (Structured Text) – язык для программирования контроллеров и операторских станций. Синтаксис ST во многом напоминает синтаксис Pascal.*

Как я думаю, тут нужно создать нечто вроде транслятора состоящего из лексического и синтаксического анализаторов, блока трансформации синтаксического дерева и блока генерации кода. Однако, раньше подобных задач решать мне не приходилось.

Пожалуйста, подскажите какую литературу лучше почитать и где можно посмотреть примеры кода подобных вещей? Особенно интересует принцип построения абстрактного синтаксического дерева и процедура получения по нему нового кода.

Comment: Книгу дракона читать

Comment: Ну, лучше "[Книги дракона](https://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1349-4.html)" вряд ли что-то есть, но это огромный труд, быстрого решения не получится... Готовый инструмент под C# для написания таких вещей — ANTLR, но если где найдете хорошее описание на русском языке — киньте и мне, pls... :)

Comment: Можете спросить у ребят здесь: https://t.me/CompilerDev